# Why type "int" is never equal to 'null'?

Tags: c#, null

```
int n == 0;

if (n == null)    
{  
    Console.WriteLine("......");  
}
```

Is it true that the result of expression (`n == null`) is always `false` since
a   **value of type `int`**  is never equal to   **`null` of type `int?`** (see warning below)

> **Warning  CS0472**    The result of the expression is always 'false' since a value of type 'int' is never equal to 'null' of type 'int?'

Comment: Because int is a value type...?

Comment: Why a question about C# can be duplicated if suggested existing answer is for JAVA?!

Comment: @Matías: I think it makes sense because .NET and Java have many similarities, and in this case it's the same concept with slightly different terminology (primitive vs value type). And when you vote to close, you pick 1 of 5 reasons, and not all votes have to have the same reason.

Comment: I see, btw, I believe that if no .NET-related existing answer was found, it could be enough to answer this and don't close it... It's just an opinion ;)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why am I getting "CS0472: The result of the expression is always true since a value of type int is never equal to null of type int?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6765144/why-am-i-getting-cs0472-the-result-of-the-expression-is-always-true-since-a-va)

Comment: An integer can never be null. Because if you type `int i = null`, it will give you compile error. Only a nullable integer can be null. Like `int? i = null`, it won't give you compile error. So that the type `System.Int32` or `int` is never equal to null.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

If you want your integer variable to allow  null values, declare it to be a [nullable type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/nullable-types/):

```
int? n = 0;
```

Note the `?` after int, which means that type can have the value `null`. Nullable types were introduced with v2.0 of the .NET Framework.

Comment: Alternatively (though I do like the shorthand `?` post-fix better) there is [`Nullable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx). -- EDIT: Additionally, you can now reference either (in this example) `n.Value` or use short-hand `int m = n ?? default(int);` (or whatever you chose to be the default value) [syntactical sugar for `int m = (n.HasValue ? n.Value : default(int));`]

Comment: @Brad true—I would be wasting much of my life if I did not use the `?` shorthand.

Comment: @Brad: there's `n.GetValueOrDefault()` as well instead of using `??`

Comment: @thecoop - yes. However, the difference is, that `??` is usually shorter, e.g. `n ?? int.MaxValue` or `n ?? int.MinValue` - or, if it makes sense in your case `n ?? 0`. The same would be for example `n.GetValueOrDefault(int.MaxValue)`. This function comes from an older .NET version, the `??` operator was introduced later, also the `?` for nullable types as in `int?`, which is equivalent to `Nullable<int>`.

Answer (score 20):

In C# using an uninitialized variable is not allowed.

So

```
int i;
Console.Writeline(i);
```

Results in a compilation error.

You can initialize int with new such as:

```
int anInt = new int();
```

This will result in the [Default value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83fhsxwc%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) for int which is 0.  In cases where you do wish to have a generic `int` one can make the int nullable with the syntax

```
int? nullableInt = null;
```

Comment: Why the downvote?  Its important to point out how initialization works in terms of nullability.  No other answer did this.  Especially considering the ambiguity of the question.  We need to ensure all ground is covered for the OP and future people who have this general question.

Comment: I downvoted because initialization wasn't even an issue (though, oddly, the OP's initialization won't compile). At the time, that's what I perceived to be the point of your answer, and I thought it off-topic. My vote appears to be locked in, however.

Comment: @Jeol B Fant - I noticed that the OP initialization won't compile.  That's what made me think of posting this answer explaining initialization and nulls in regards to the C# lang.

Answer (score 6):

Because `int` is a value type rather than a reference type. The C# Language Specification doesn't allow an `int` to contain null. Try compiling this statement:

```
int x = null ;
```

and see what you get.

You get the compiler warning because it's a pointless test and the compiler knows it.

Answer (score 4):

"Value types" in .NET (like int, double, and bool) cannot, by definition, be null - they always have an actual value assigned.  Check out [this good intro](http://www.albahari.com/valuevsreftypes.aspx) to value types vs. reference types.

Answer (score 2):

The usage of NULL applies to Pointers and References in general. A value 0 assigned to an integer is not null. However if you can assign a pointer to the integer and assign it to NULL, the statement is valid.

To sum up =>

```
 /*Use the keyword 'null' while assigning it to pointers and references. Use 0 for integers.*/
```

Answer (score 2):

Very simply put, an int is a very basic item.  It's small and simple so that it can be handled quickly.  It's handled as the value directly, not along the object/pointer model.  As such, there's no legal "NULL" value for it to have.  It simply contains what it contains.  0 means a 0.  Unlike a pointer, where it being 0 would be NULL.  An object storing a 0 would have a non-zero pointer still.

If you get the chance, take the time to do some old-school C or assembly work, it'll become much clearer.

Answer (score 2):

```
 public static int? n { get; set; } = null;
```

OR

```
 public static Nullable<int> n { get; set; }
```

or

```
 public static int? n = null;
```

or

```
 public static int? n
```

or just

```
 public static int? n { get; set; } 


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {


    Console.WriteLine(n == null);

     //you also can check using 
     Console.WriteLine(n.HasValue);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

The null keyword is a literal that represents a null reference, one that does not refer to any object. 
In programming, nullable types are a feature of the type system of some programming languages which allow the value to be set to the special value NULL instead of the usual possible values of the data type.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/null
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null

Answer (score 1):

No, because `int` is a value type. `int` is a `Value` type like `Date`, `double`, etc. So there is no way to assigned a `null` value.