# Why int can't be null? How does nullable int (int?) work in C#?

Tags: c#, object, int, nullable

I am new to C# and just learned that objects can be null in C# but `int` can't.

Also how does nullable int (`int?`) work in C#?

Comment: I would invest in a good book on C#. You're bound to have lots more questions on basic syntax like this and asking them individually on SO would take up a lot of time.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6191339/why-type-int-is-never-equal-to-null

Comment: @Bart: I see that got closed as a dupe of the one jleedev linked to, but this question is much more specific to C# with nullable value types...

Comment: ppl are more interested in closing questions and finding duplicates rather then looking whats being asked and answering it. This question is not duplicate of all marked but ppl still have marked it duplicate,  rest agreed and closed it. I think none of them looked at question once.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`int` is a primitive type and only `ReferenceType`s (objects) are nullable. You can make an `int` nullable by wrapping it in an object:

```
System.Nullable<int> i;
```

-or-

```
int? i;
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/nullable-types/using-nullable-types

Comment: Is `int?` slower than `int` is? Does it use more memory?

Comment: @AaronFranke yeah, gets wrapped in an extra object.

Answer (score 3):

An int is a value type. It is really of type Int32. Objects that can be nullable are reference types. At a basic level the difference is that a value type will store the value with the variable where a reference type will store a reference to the value. A reference can be null, meaning that it doesn't point to a  value. Where a value type always has a value.

Nullable wraps a value type to allow you to have the option of being null. Using int? is just a compiler shortcut to declare a nullable type.

Answer (score 2):

Value types like `int` contain direct values rather than references like `ReferenceType`. A value cannot be null but a reference can be null which means it is pointing to nothing. A value cannot have nothing in it. A value always contain some kind of value

Nullable or Nullable types are special value types which in addition to normal values of value types also support additional null value just like reference types

Answer (score 2):

You can have a nullable int by using int? or `Nullable<int>` both are exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Objects are reference types and they can reference nothing or NULL, however int is a value type, which can only hold a value, and cannot reference anything.

Answer (score 0):

Primitive int type cannot express null in its binary representation, but `Nullable<int>` added an extra byte to express the null information of this value.

Comment: Someone gives the down vote should show the reason.   Nullable<T> add an extra private bool filed `hasValue` to the structure definition to express null of int, besides, the CLR need to be revised a little to deal with this special structure when comparing it with null.  The primitive int could not represent null since all its binary permutations represent value of int, in the condition that it has 4 bytes in the stack.

Comment: I didn't downvote it, but may have been due to citing an obscure fact about the memory layout without any supporting documentation.  Otherwise, I'm not sure.