# How to assign int variable to empty in c#?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

How to assign int variable to empty in c#?

At present, variable is defaulting to 0.

variable as declared :

```
public int Timesaday { get; set; }
```

I tried with Nullable..  `public int? Timesaday { get; set; }`

Expected result, variable should not assign default value = 0. by default value should be empty.

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean default for int? is null. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29153832/what-is-the-default-value-of-the-nullable-type-int-including-question-mark

Comment: You can't assign empty value to int type variable. To avoid 0 you should assign NULL value to it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set null value to int in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19522225/how-to-set-null-value-to-int-in-c)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 public static int? Timesaday { get; set; } = null;
```

OR

```
 public static Nullable<int> Timesaday { get; set; }
```

or

```
 public static int? Timesaday = null;
```

or

```
 public static int? Timesaday
```

or just

```
 public static int? Timesaday { get; set; } 


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {


    Console.WriteLine(Timesaday == null);

     //you also can check using 
     Console.WriteLine(Timesaday.HasValue);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

The null keyword is a literal that represents a null reference, one that does not refer to any object. 
In programming, nullable types are a feature of the type system of some programming languages which allow the value to be set to the special value NULL instead of the usual possible values of the data type.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/null
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null

Comment: FYI: As @TheGeneral said there is no need to set it since it's null by default.

Answer (score 4):

All `Nullable` types are intialized to `null`

```
public static int ? Timesaday
{
    get;
    set;
}

public static void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine(Timesaday == null);
}
```

Output

```
True
```

[Demo here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/s85LwL)

---

If you look at the source for a `Nullable<T>` [referencesource.microsoft.com](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/R/ffebe438fd9cbf0e.html), you can see unless you pass in value through the constructor, its going to be `HasValue == false` and no value

```
public struct Nullable<T> where T : struct
{
    private bool hasValue; 
    internal T value;

    [System.Runtime.Versioning.NonVersionable]
    public Nullable(T value) {
        this.value = value;
        this.hasValue = true;
    }
```

...