# How to pass empty string to nullable int

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, abp

I have this property

```
public int? CodigoBanco { get; set; }
```

An when i try to send it to server in this way

```
codigoBanco: ""
```

I have the following error

> The following errors were detected during validation:\r\n - The JSON
> value could not be converted to System.Nullable`1[System.Int32]

Comment: You can't do that. `int?` is not equal to `string`, you might use string for `CodigoBanco`

Comment: Or leave the property codigoBanco out of the json or set it to null (`codigoBanco: null`)

Comment: @D-Shih can i set some convention so the server can handle it and auto convert empty string to null?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52177006/how-to-assign-int-variable-to-empty-in-c

Comment: you need a custom json converter, see [this qa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57334833). `codigoBanco: ""` is not a valid integer. if you want to pass a null integer properly, you should just skip the property altogether (do not mention it in the json).

Comment: @Maytham Since the dafault value for input is an empty string the property is send as codigoBanco: "" . Ralf suggestion worked very well to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two ways to resolve the problem:

1. Specify `null` (not empty string) and it will be successfully mapped. `codigoBanco: null` or remove this property at all from client-side(the default will be the same `null`)
2. Write custom convertaion at backend-side, something like:

   `CodigoBanco = int.Parse(codigoBanco == "" || codigoBanco.Length = 0 ? null : codigoBanco);`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what's your point of doing that but simple way just casting:

```
CodigoBanco  =Convert.ToInt32(codigoBanco==""?null:codigoBanco)
```

the convert returns 0 into your int? property

Answer (score 0):

As @Ralf suggested, I removed all properties with empty string from json. This solved my problem:

```
function removeEmptyOrNull(obj){
    Object.keys(obj).forEach(k =>
        (obj[k] && typeof obj[k] === 'object') && removeEmptyOrNull(obj[k]) ||
        (!obj[k] && obj[k] !== undefined) && delete obj[k]
    );
    return obj;
};
```